# Moving averages algorithm over a given image as open cv Mat object, the transformed image does not look correct

Tags: c++, opencv, computer-vision, moving-average

I'm learning computer vision with opencv c++, and as a beginner exercise I'm supposed to implement the moving averages algorithm to achieve the blur effect. following the snippet of the function which takes the input grayscale image, and display's output transformed image, but the transformed image looks incorrect to me, am I missing some opencv specific details or the algorithm itself is wrong?

Something like encoding between datatypes? I tried printing value of pointVal (given in the code, this is the pixel value of a transformed pixel) it prints a char!

```
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>
#include <opencv2/core.hpp>
#include <opencv2/imgcodecs.hpp>
#include <opencv2/highgui.hpp>
#include <opencv2/imgproc.hpp>
#include <math.h>
#include <algorithm>
using namespace std;
using namespace cv;

void displayImage(Mat &img,unsigned int time=0){
    imshow("frame",img);
    waitKey(time);
}


void movingAverageTransform(Mat &img){
    displayImage(img);
    unsigned int winSize = 3;
    int trows = img.rows-winSize+1;
    int tcols = img.cols-winSize+1;
    Mat transformed(trows,tcols, CV_8UC1); 

    // accumulate first column prefix sums
    for(int i =1;i<img.rows;i++)
        img.at<u_char>(i,0) += img.at<u_char>(i-1,0);
    
    // accumulate first row prefix sums
    for(int j = 1;j<img.cols;j++)
        img.at<u_char>(0,j)+= img.at<u_char>(0,j-1);

    // compute the rectangular submatrix prefix sums.
    for(int i =1;i<img.rows;i++)
        for(int j = 1;j<img.cols;j++)
            img.at<u_char>(i,j) += (img.at<u_char>(i-1,j) + img.at<u_char>(i,j-1) - img.at<u_char>(i-1,j-1));
    // now use the formula for computing the moving average of a sub matrix of size winSize X winSize by sliding it across the image 
    for(int i = 0;i<trows;i++){
        for(int j = 0;j<tcols;j++){
            u_char pointVal = img.at<u_char>(i+winSize -1,j+winSize-1);
            if(i>=1)
                pointVal -= img.at<u_char>(i-1,j+winSize-1);
            if(j>=1)
                pointVal -=img.at<u_char>(i+winSize -1,j-1);
            if(i>=1 and j>=1)
                pointVal += img.at<u_char>(i-1,j-1);
            transformed.at<u_char>(i,j) = pointVal/(winSize*winSize);
        }
    }
    displayImage(transformed);
}

int main(){
    string imPath = "/home/panirpal/workspace/Learning/Courses/computer-vision/cpp/data/frm.png";
    Mat img = imread(imPath,IMREAD_GRAYSCALE);
    if(!img.empty())
        movingAverageTransform(img);
    
    return 0;
}
```

Below in the transform formula, T is the transform image, I is the input image and (i,j) is the co-ordinate in Transform image. And I[x][y] in the formula means the sum of the sub matrix starting at 0,0 and ending at x,y in Input image I.

The transform formula :

[image: computation]

Input image :

[image: input image]

Transformed image :

[image: transformed image]

I see that the output image is not blurred but transformed into something else entirely!

Comment: You can create e.g. 5-by-5 image with artificial values, do the computation by hand and compare the intermediate and final result with the ones computed by the code.

Comment: @Quimby I tried to print the value of pointVal I see it gives a char, should I do a cast to int or something?

Comment: did you know that you are calculating an "integral image"? what do you know about the value range of an `u_char`? -- if you are surprised that printing a char prints a char, then you need to review your C/C++

Comment: In the integral image, the further right and down you go, the higher the pixel values will be. How high? If all pixels have a value of 255, then the bottom-right pixel would have a value of `255*width*height`. Typically it’ll be lower, but definitely much larger than 255. What value can you fit in a pixel of a `CV_8U` image? No more than 255. So what is all this `+=` doing in your code? Overflowing. Again and again.

Comment: Also, computing the integral image for a 3x3 filter is much less efficient than just computing the filter directly, in the naive way. For larger filters you can do the separable convolution. The integral image becomes efficient only when you need to compute filters of different sizes for the same image.

Comment: Bonus: `u_char` is non-standard C++.

Comment: @Christoph Rackwitz I do not know about integral image, let me learn more about it!